# Setup type as macro parameter returns error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Tags: c++

I am trying to do some code generation.

When I want to set type of returning value with the parameter compile fails.
Why compiler returns me error?

```
    #define MODULE_GETTER(module_type, interface_type) \
        public: \
            static #interface_type * Instance##interface_type (void) \
            { \
                return NULL;\
            }


    class MyModuleType :
    public IMyModuleInterface
    {
        MODULE_GETTER(MyModuleType,IMyModuleInterface)
    private:
    ...
    };
```

When I change `static #interface_type *` into `static int *` or any other predefined type, code compiles without error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a macro definition, `#` is the stringification operator, which wraps its operand in quotes to make a string literal; so the macro expands into

```
static "IMyModuleInterface" * InstanceIMyModuleInterface (void)
```

which is nonsense. Get rid of the rogue `#` and it should compile.